# Automate login (OpenId Connect/oAuth authentication) from Web app

Tags: authentication, openid

I have a login web page (https://aenormas.aenor.com) in which email and password are requested and what I would like to do is "automate" said login, let me explain. What I want to do is that from a page of a web application it reaches the final web page as if it had logged in (email and password) and had clicked on the 'Login' button. In short, I know the login details and I want to skip the login window. By the way, authentication is implemented with OpenId Connect /oAuth.

Thank you and regards, Iñaki.

In short, I know the login details and I want to skip the login window (OpendId Connect / oAuth authentication).

In short, I know the login details and I want to skip the login window (OpendId Connect / oAuth authentication).